# Function to filter rows under certain conditions in a data set

Tags: r, filter, conditional-statements, data-manipulation

I want to delete all rows in this dataset where `coder = 6`, under the condition that for the same id and arm the value coder 99 is present. In the picture these are the lines 5, 7, 11, 15 and 17. Does anyone know how I can proceed?

```
df = structure(list(id = c("001", "003", "003", "006", "007", "007", 
"012", "012", "017", "020", "022", "022", "025", "026", "030", 
"030", "030", "030", "034", "034", "036", "036", "038", "040", 
"040", "042", "042", "047", "047", "049", "049", "051", "051", 
"052", "052", "054", "054", "059", "061", "062", "062", "063", 
"063", "063", "063", "064", "064", "065", "065", "065", "065", 
"066", "066", "067", "067", "068", "068", "069", "069", "073", 
"075", "076", "076", "077", "081", "081", "085", "093", "093", 
"095", "095", "096", "096", "096", "096", "101", "102", "102", 
"104", "104", "106", "106", "107", "107", "107", "108", "110", 
"114", "114", "115", "115", "116", "116", "116", "120", "201", 
"201", "201", "202", "202", "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", 
"207"), arm = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), coder = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 
6, 6, 99, 6, 6, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 6, 6, 99, 6, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 
99, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 99, 6, 6, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 99, 
6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 99, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 99, 6, 99, 6, 6, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 
99, 99, 99)), row.names = c(NA, -106L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Make your data reproducible, `dput(myData)`, and add expected output as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(id, arm) %>% 
  filter(!(any(coder == 99) & coder == 6))

# A tibble: 80 x 3
# Groups:   id, arm [80]
   id      arm coder
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 001       1     6
 2 003       1     6
 3 003       2     6
 4 006       1     6
 5 007       1    99
 6 012       1    99
 7 017       1     6
 8 020       1     6
 9 022       1    99
10 025       1     6
# ... with 70 more rows
```

Comment: Sorry, i meant I want do delete all such rows. My fault. But thanks for the answer :)

Comment: No worries, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option using `subset` + `ave`

```
subset(
  df,
  !(ave(coder == 99, id, arm, FUN = any) & coder == 6)
)
```

gives

```
   id      arm coder
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 001       1     6
 2 003       1     6
 3 003       2     6
 4 006       1     6
 5 007       1    99
 6 012       1    99
 7 017       1     6
 8 020       1     6
 9 022       1    99
10 025       1     6
# ... with 70 more rows
```